# How to convert a DateTime variable in awk to seconds?

Tags: command-line, awk

I have a variable in which stores the DateTime in awk

```
test=$(f["DateTime"])
print "Printing Test variable:",test
```

Output:

```
 Printing Test variable:,"2018-12-18 18:36:55"
```

I want to convert the value in test to seconds

Could anybody tell me how to do that in awk

Using mktime() is giving -1 as output

```
    print mktime(gensub(/[ :-]/," ","g",test))
```

My Input data (CSV File)is like below

```
DateTime,Dealer,Some Value,State,CallEndTime,Some Value,TotalDuration,,..

 "2019-01-07 11:35:42","Car","fab","foo",,"bar","100","boo",..
```

I got the DateTime value from this,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have GNU awk (`gawk`) you can use its `mktime` function - however the input must be a space-separated *datespec* of the form `"YYYY MM DD HH MM SS [DST]"`. The date fields in your variable are in the right order, but you will need to replace the delimiters with spaces:

```
$ gawk -v test="2018-12-18 18:36:55" 'BEGIN{print mktime(gensub(/[ :-]/," ","g",test))}'
1545176215
```

See for example [Time Functions in the GNU Awk User's Guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html#index-mktime_0028_0029-function-_0028gawk_0029)

---

If your string is enclosed in double quotes, you will need to remove those as well:

```
$ gawk -v test='"2018-12-18 18:36:55"' 'BEGIN{print mktime(gensub(/[ ":-]/," ","g",test))}'
1545176215
```

Comment: I tried this,but its giving me -1 as O/P, Please check the edited question

Comment: @mittu please see update